# r Using action buttons to hide/show checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

Say I had the following code...

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      actionButton("fishButton", label = "Fish"),
      checkboxGroupInput("Check1",label=h4 ("Fish:"), choices = c("Bass","Shark","Tuna")),
      actionButton("reptileButton", label = "Reptile"),
      checkboxGroupInput("Check2",label=h4 ("Reptile:"), choices = c("Komodo","Skink","Snake")),
      actionButton("mammalButton", label = "Mammal"),
      checkboxGroupInput("Check3",label=h4 ("Mammals:"), choices = c("Dog","Cat","Bear")),
      actionButton("birdButton", label = "Bird"),
      checkboxGroupInput("Check4",label=h4 ("Birds:"), choices = c("Budgie","Parrot","Cockatiel")),
      actionButton("amphibianButton", label = "Amphibian"),
      checkboxGroupInput("Check5",label=h4 ("Amphibian:"), choices = c("Frog","Toad","Salamander"))
    )
```

Is there a way to use conditional panels to hide/show the checkboxGroups by clicking on the appropriate actionButton? As I understand it the actionButton only stores an integer that starts at 0 and increases by 1 with each click of the button, which doesn´t seem very helpful in this case.  Would it be possible to have a conditional panel that only showed itself when it´s actionButton value was an even number or somesuch?

Comment: You can use uiOutput() on the ui side and checkboxGroupInput() generated on the server side (probably) to do this. I have not done this specific thing, but use server side inputs all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do using [shinyJS](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package:

```
install.packages("shinyjs")
```

In the ui, init the field as hidden and call the toggle on the button click

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  actionButton("fishButton", label = "Fish"),
  hidden(
    checkboxGroupInput("Check1",label=h4 ("Fish:"), choices = c("Bass","Shark","Tuna"))
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$fishButton, {
    toggle("Check1")
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, I used your solution, but now I have a problem when filtering my data: `if (exists(input$Check1)){datas <- subset(datas, City == input$Check1)}` could you please help me solve this? I do not think the exist function will work here

Comment: a reproducible example would help, but I guess you are trying to subset your data based on checkbox marked. Probably this will work:
  df <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$Check1)){
      subset(data, choices == input$Check1)  
    }
  })